# How to navigate between fragment programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

**Background:** I created project by choosing Navigation Drawer template and my `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`.

**Problem:** I need to traverse/navigate to another UI fragment (lets say `FragmentA`) for a result on click of a button from UI `fragmentB`. Something similar to `startActivityForResult`.

I declared `navController` as public variable in `MainAcitivty` and tried to access it in the fragment and execute `navController.navigate(MENU_ID);` with no luck.

Any suggestion how it can be achieved?

Comment: The when I have to use this it worked for me https://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Answer (score 0):

You've to call `navigate` with either the navigation action id or pass the `NavDirections` object generated by `safeArgs` plugin. Here's one [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigating-with-safeargs-bf26c17b1269) on how to use `safeArgs`

**Safe Args Example**

```kotlin
navController.navigate(
    MoviesFragmentDirections.actionMoviesFragmentToMovieDetailFragment(movieId)
)
```

**Action Id Example**

```kotlin
navController.navigate(
    R.id.action_movies_fragment_to_movie_detail_fragment
)
```

[image: sample]